# Swapping command and control keys quickly (OS Mojave)

Tags: keyboard

I normally work on a keyboard with the control and command keys swapped via the "Modifier Keys" option in Settings. However, if someone else (e.g. coworker) wants to pair or show me some stuff on my laptop, it's much harder for them to navigate because they're used to the control/command keys in their default spots.

I'm wondering if there's a way to quickly swap between these two "modes", similar to the way you can quickly switch between different written languages via a shortcut. It's cumbersome to go to the modifier keys each time and restore the defaults, and then change the modifier keys back to what I'm used to afterwards. I'd also prefer to not use multiple physical keyboards if possible, as I know you can have different settings on different physical keyboards.

Comment: No there isn't the best solution would be to change how you use your computer so that you don't have this issue when working at a different machine. I appreciate that isn't the answer you want, but it is the simplest solution.